# mkdepent.py permission denied ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, gfortran

- I would like to run a `Fortran` model under `UBUNTU 14.04`.
- I use gfortran compiler.
- The program contains a `mkdepends.py` for building the model which requires python 2 or later.
- Python 2.7.5-5ubuntu3, python3.4 3.4.0-2ubuntu1 are installed by ubuntu software center as default.
- I installed the `python-numpy 1:1.8.2-0ubuntu0.1` with software center too. * Moreover the `UV-CDAT` is installed according to: `https://github.com/UV-CDAT/uvcdat/wiki/Install-on-Linux`.
- The path of `f2py` is set in compiler option as: `F2PY=/usr/local/uvcdat/2.0.0/bin/f2py` and 
  `F2PY_OPTS=--fcompiler-exec=$(COMPILER) $(LDFLAGS)`
- When I compile the model with `sudo` make command the following error message is written: 
      make[1]: execvp: ./mkdepend.py: Permission denied
- Could someone write me what can i do ?

Comment: What are the permission bits on mkdepend.py? Should be probably 755 (executable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the script is executable on UNIX file system.

```
 chmod u+x mkdepend.py
```

With or without `sudo`, depending on the file ownership.

[For further information see tutorial on UNIX file permissions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm).